# How to reset MTK engineering mode to the default settings?

Tags: settings, rom-flashing

2020.1.11 Renewal
Maybe the field of MTK engineering mode is the most mysterious field of the smartphone. It’s like a top-secret. No matter the questions post on anywhere, no one can answer it.

Below is the original question:
I have an old question, until now no one can give me an exact answer. I looked up the question on the Internet many times, but I don't find the answer.
I have an old smartphone, its CPU is MTK6589.
As we knew, the CPU made by MTK has an engineering mode. For example the command *#*#3646633#*#*, we can make some setting in the mode. 
I want to know, what does this mode use for? Just to test the device? Or make some underlying setting?
If I changed the settings, how can I reset it to the default value?
Restore factory setting?
I tried this, but the value in engineering mode can not recover to default.
Flash official firmware?
I tried this. After I flashed it, all the values seem to recover. But I saw some people said that this is just changed the value which it displays, the value saved in CPU can not be recovered. 
So can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: You seem to have a number of questions. It would help to [edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/220175/edit) your question to include the make and model along with what version of Android OS your device is running. Please be aware that CPU is different than an Operating System like Android

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks for your advice. I edited my question.

Comment: Speculation: If flashing official firmware doesn't repair the issue, then the settings are in EEPROM on the SOC or radio chipsets. The only way to know what was the original values would be to keep a record before changing. I suspect that these settings are only for QA in the factory or QA by the carrier and similarly no safeguards from bricking or bad state. Its also possible that depending on the MTK motherboard version that [JTAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JTAG) via test pads is needed to properly reset such settings.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks. I found another article about this problem, for your reference. https://xiaomifirmware.com/guides-and-tips/reset-engineering-mode-settings-back-to-defaults/